# MvvmCross MvxBind syntax to bind to ViewModel itself (not to ViewModel.Property)

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, data-binding, mvvmcross

The usual MvvmCross syntax for binding to a ViewModel property with the `MvxBind` attribute in an android layout file looks like this:

```
<SomeControl
    local:MvxBind="ViewProperty ViewModelProperty" />
```

So to access `ViewModel.ViewModelProperty` I can just type in the property name.

But what is the correct syntax to access the `ViewModel` itself (not one of its properties)?

With the fluent API, you can probably do something like this (not tested):

```
this.CreateBindingSet<SomeView, string>()
    .Bind(someControl)
        .For(v => v.Text)
        .To(vm => vm)
    .Apply();
```

What is the equivalent for that with the `MvxBind` syntax in a layout file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A `.` should do it.

```
<SomeControl local:MvxBind="ViewProperty ." />
```

But there is even a shorter way (which I do not use)
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/databinding#swiss

> If $SourcePath$ is omitted or a single period "." is used, then the Source used is the whole of the ViewModel.

So you should be able to just do something like this

```
<SomeControl local:MvxBind="ViewProperty" />
```